# How can I turn this command into Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a script that almost I convert into Ansible playbook. Here is an issue where I want to get the Ansible host (target) public IP address
for this in the script we are doing something like this.

```bash
IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)

cat > /tmp/orgconfig << EOF
MSIP=$(hostname -i)
VHOST_ALIAS="${IP}:9001"
# Optionally configure TLS/SSL for virtual host.
# VHOST_SSL=y     # Set to "y" to enable TLS/SSL on the virtual host.
# KEYSTORE_JAR=   # JAR file containing the cert and private key.
# KEYSTORE_NAME=  # Name of the keystore.
# KEYSTORE_ALIAS= # The key alias.
# KEY_PASSWORD=   # The key password, if it has one.
# Specify the analytics group.
# AXGROUP=axgroup-001 # Default name is axgroup-001.
EOF
```

But here challenge is even I am not able to create variable like

```bash
IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
```

and also not able to find a way to get public IP address
I want to use public IP in `blockinfile`.

Comment: Why not use [the dig plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

> I am not able to create variable like `IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)`

this can be achieved like

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather IP from DNS
    shell:
      cmd: dig {{ inventory_hostname }} +short
    register: IP

  - name: Show IP
    debug:
      msg: "{{ IP.stdout }}"
```

by [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show IP] ***********
ok: [test1.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.1
ok: [test2.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.2
```

A better approach might be to use Ansible [Lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) modules and [`dig` – query DNS using the dnspython library](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html). You may have a look into the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html#examples).

Regarding

> ... I want to use public ip in BLOCKINFILE ...

you may have a look into [`template` – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) and for syntax like `VHOST_ALIAS="{{ IP.stdout }}:9001"`.

Comment: i do the same but it showing empty  TASK [Show IP]******************************************************************************************task path: /root/playbooks/getip.yaml:13
ok: [target-aio] => {
    "msg": ""
}